# passing id through Link to getServerSideProps :next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i have some alert compoents. from  each of the compoent i want to pass the itm._id

and recive it in [itm].jsx in the same folder in the [itm].jsx i want to use it in the  getServerSideProps funtion to fetch data

index.jsx

```
  <div className="question11">
            {data.map((itm) => (
              <Link
                key={itm._id}
                href={{
                  pathname: "/[itm]",
                  query: itm._id,
                }}
                as={`/${encodeURIComponent(
                  itm.Name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 - _ . ~]/g, "").replace(
                    / /g,
                    "-"
                  )
                )}`}
              >
                <Alert className="question13">{itm.Name}</Alert>
              </Link>
            ))}
          </div>
```

flowing is the  getServerSideProps function the error now i am getting is that

`Server Error FetchError: invalid json response body at https://askover.wixten.com/questone/[object%20Object] reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

i think the error is id is recived as object how do i fix this

[itm].jsx

```
export async function getServerSideProps(query) {
  var id1 = query;

  console.log(id1);
  const queryRequest = fetch("https://askover.wixten.com/questone/" + id1).then(
    async (res) => await res.json()
  );
  const answerRequest = fetch(
    "https://askover.wixten.com/answersapi/" + id1
  ).then(async (res) => await res.json());

  const responses = await Promise.all([queryRequest, answerRequest]);
  const [posts, answerPosts] = await Promise.all(responses);

  return {
    props: {
      posts,
      answerPosts,
    },
  };
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does console.log id1 show?

Comment: i cant comsole.log because of error

Comment: Can you try query.query

Comment: i have added the screenshot of error

Comment: still i am getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
In Link Tag pass query as

```
<div className="question11">
            {data.map((itm) => (
              <Link
                key={itm._id}
                href={{
                  pathname: "/[itm]",
                  query: {id: itm._id},
                }}
                as={`/${encodeURIComponent(
                  itm.Name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 - _ . ~]/g, "").replace(
                    / /g,
                    "-"
                  )
                )}`}
              >
                <Alert className="question13">{itm.Name}</Alert>
              </Link>
            ))}
          </div>
```

And in getserversideprops you can access it like this

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  console.log(contex.params.id)  //If doesn't work use context.query.id
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you see the documentation for `getServerSideProps` you'll see the parameter is called `context` - this is an object, not the id you're expecting.

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  return {
    props: {}, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```

Quote:

The context parameter is an object containing the following keys:

- req: The HTTP IncomingMessage object.
- res: The HTTP response object.
- query: An object representing the query string.

(others removed)

Therefore your query params will be in `context.query`.

Try this:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const query = context.query
  console.log(query?.itm);
  // ^  
}
```

You named the query param `itm` (as the file is called [itm].tsx) - so context.query.itm should give you the value you need.
Check in the console before you add the URL.

Comment: i tryed ur method i console.loged    console.log(context.query); and in terminal i got  { '61955c1c38fdb90023c02bbe': '', itm: 'What-is-dubai-expo' }  from this i want only the id

Comment: great - so what I wrote above - `query?.itm` is what you want

Answer (score 1):

You have to receive **itm** from query like below. query itself a object. Inside object your path variable exists as your dynamic filename. You are fetching data by object. you have to fetch data by **itm** alias as **id1**.

```js
export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {
  var {itm: id1} = query;
  ...

  return {
    props: {
      posts,
      answerPosts,
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you're not destructuring the query from the parameters of getServerSideProps
The error tells you you are making a request to  /[object object] which means your id is not a string it's the entire props object of the getServerSideProps function.

export async function getServerSideProps(query)

replace it with

export async function getServerSideProps({query})